# Why does Red Hat 7.3 (not RHEL) `ls` show file sizes in bytes, even when `-k` or `--block-size` is specified?

Tags: linux, ls, redhat-classic

We have an old Linux server, some OS version information, as follows:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dm.inside.com 2.4.18-17.7.xsmp #1 SMP Tue Oct 8 12:37:04 EDT 2002 i686 unknown
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Linux release 7.3 (Valhalla)
```

No matter how I issue 'ls', file size is always shown in bytes,as follows:

```
$ ls -l catalina.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 qbase    qbase    13136665 Aug  1 13:00 catalina.out
ls -lk catalina.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 qbase    qbase    13136706 Aug  1 13:01 catalina.out
$ ls -l --block-size=1024 catalina.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 qbase    qbase    13136706 Aug  1 13:01 catalina.out
```

'alias' command shows that 'ls' command is not aliased. So what could be wrong?

Comment: What do `which ls` and `ls --version` show?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it? You didn’t specify the `-h` (human-readable) switch.

Comment: @Madoc: `$which ls
/bin/ls
$ ls --version
ls (fileutils) 4.1
Written by Richard Stallman and David MacKenzie.

Copyright (C) 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: @Daniel: No! See this on another Linux server: `$ ls -l catalina.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qbase qbase 15403660 Aug  1 16:53 catalina.out
$ ls -lk catalina.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qbase qbase 15046 Aug  1 16:53 catalina.out` You see, the file sizes are shown differenty. Besides, I know '-h' option, I just curious about why the '-k' or '--block-size' options don't work?

Comment: Guys! Please stick to the **title of the question**, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2013-03/msg00018.html // Also related: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way it works in that version of `ls`, whether due to a bug or by design. You can verify that the behavior of `ls -l --block-size=1024` changes between `fileutils-4.1.11` and `coreutils-5.0` (note that `fileutils` and a few other packages were merged into a new `coreutils` package at that point).

Here are links to the tarballs if you're interested in rebuilding them:

- http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/fetish/fileutils-4.1.11.tar.bz2
- ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-5.0.tar.bz2

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll try to install something to replace the function of ls

Answer (score 1):

If you use `-h` (human-readable) like `ls -lh` you will see the size in KB or MB ...

Comment: If you could include a link to the documentation this would be a good answer.

Comment: Yes, I know the -h option. I'm asking **why "-k" or "--block-size" options don't work**, not for a "solution" to show MB or KB.